# Jenkins release automation

Tags: maven, jenkins, automation, release

Is there a way to configure a single Jenkins job to perform the release of each newer version of my application?

i.e, I would like to know in detail if it's possible to do the following tasks without any human intervention. I'm using **SVN** as well as **Artifactory**.

1. Branch from the tag to be released
2. Change the snapshot versions in pom files to release versions (for each dependency defined in pom)
3. Take release build (EAR)
4. Deploy it in Weblogic instance.
5. Prepare release note
6. Tag the release

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find 'Execute concurrent builds if necessary' option and check it.

Answer (score 3):

It can be fully automated using Multijob plugin (Also with a regular single job, but using Multijob it will be easier and you can use Maven targets instead of some manual shell scripting ).
The workflow starts with:

1. commit and push to git
2. hook in git should trigger a job by http POST, so u need to configure your job to accept remote triggering. You can pass the branch name as parameter
3. job started, cloning the branch (git plugin)
4. start Maven project to `mvn clean install` and check unit tests (optional)
5. start Maven project to `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` to omit the `SNAPSHOT` from `pom.xml`
6. tag the branch (using shell block and simple git commands)
7. merge to master branch (optionally)
8. start Maven project to `mvn deploy` to deploy to weblogic (weblogic should be configured in `~/.m2/settings.xml` as the repository for deploying the artifacts

**NOTE:** all tasks can be also in 1 job with some shell scripting. the best practices is to use plugins but sometimes you will find it easier to use shell scripting for some tasks.